# Can I relax the attribution requirement for my CC licensed work? How?

Tags: attribution, cc-by

I have published my CC-licensed work on a web page (CC BY 4.0, but it could be any CC license with a BY clause). I want to encourage re-use by making it clear how to attribute my work. In fact, I want to make it even easier than [the best practice guidelines](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution).

I can see, for example, that the Stack Exchange notice line reads:

> ...user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)

And the [Pepper&Carrot](https://www.peppercarrot.com) notice line reads:

> Webcomic, artworks and texts are licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) license, unless otherwise noted in the page. Attribution to "David Revoy, www.davidrevoy.com".

(The P&C blog happens to contain a helpful entry ["Best practices for attribution"](https://www.peppercarrot.com/en/article405/best-practices-for-attribution) that includes instructions for minified attribution - but that entry isn't directly linked from anywhere that I can see.)

Is there a *preferred or standard* way to link to my own, relaxed definition of "reasonable" from my notice line? (Of course remixers can still follow the regular guidelines if they prefer.)

Put another way, is there documented guidance on *how* I should insert a link to attribution guidelines in the notices below?

> 1. ["Example"](https://www.example.com) by Full Name, licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).
> 2. ["Example"](https://www.example.com) by Myname, [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
> 3. Post by Myname, [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)

Or do I just have to do it... reasonably?

Comment: of course the answer could be, "no, there is no guidance on how to do this" :)

Comment: links suggested by CC https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-insist-on-the-exact-placement-of-the-attribution-credit and https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution#Don.27t_make_it_too_complicated

Answer (score 1):

You could have a link to FAQ page giving an example(s) of how you'd like to be attributed as well as any additional license grants **in addition to** the CC license you are willing to grant (you cannot add additional restrictions to a CC license but you can always grant additional permissions).  For an example xkcd has a pretty good one: https://xkcd.com/license.html

Comment: but where on the copyright line do I put that link?

Comment: xkcd puts that on the bottom every page.   If you are the original copyright holder you do not need to attribute yourself according to the CC-BY license and could put your license explanation anywhere on the site you want (it is up to anyone who re-uses your work to comply).  But if you wanted to attribute yourself in such a fashion you could simply have the CC BY 4.0 link direct to your FAQ - your FAQ would then state the various ways you are happy to be attributed as well as give a link to the actual license.  Or you could add a (more details) and have that link to your FAQ.